# How to store timestamp in mysql database with timezone which sent by iphone app

Tags: php, mysql, objective-c, web-services, timezone

I am developing a iPhone app which need to store time data with client time zone in a remote mysql database. 
This is doing by calling a php web service  and store data in mysql database. What is the best way to find user timezone and send to web service.

edit:

```
 NSTimeZone *tzone  = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
 NSTimeInterval timeInt = [dateTime timeIntervalSince1970 ];
 NSNumber *timeStamp=[NSNumber numberWithInt:timeInt];

 NSString *zone = [tzone name];
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/mytask/"];

 ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", timeStamp] forKey:@"task_time_stamp"];
[request setPostValue:zone forKey:@"task_time_zone"];
```

How to save time stamp in MySql database with client timezone. is there any other approach.

Comment: This is a notification app and my problem is to send emails in a particular time. If i store timestamp from iPhone it will differ from the web server time.

Answer (score 1):

```
SET time_zone = 'America/New_York';
```

this can change the time zone setting of mysql db .execute before insert . if u want to know the current time-zone in php u can use `date_default_timezone_get` .

Comment: How to send the timezone to the webservice

Answer (score 1):

Date().getTimezoneOffset() this will help you.